# boost python 3.7: prints from cpp and python are misordered

Tags: python, c++, boost, printf

I'm using boost python library to wrap some cpp module.

Every method in this cpp module starts with a verbosity print (done by `fprintf()`).
A python script calls these methods one by one, each call followed by a verbosity print (done by `print()`).

I ran this script with both python 2.7 and 3.7, and noticed a difference with regards to how these prints are ordered.

With **python 2.7**, prints are properly ordered: first - print from the cpp module, then - print from the python script, and so on.
But with **python 3.7**, prints are misordered: cpp module's prints are grouped together, appearing only AFTER python script's prints.

Does anyone know why?

Python script code:

```
module = Module()
module.func1()
print("from script #1")
module.func2()
print("from script #2")
module.func3()
print("from script #3")
```

C++ module code:

```
class Module{
    void func1(){
      printf("from module #1");
    }
    void func2(){
      printf("from module #2");
    }
    void func3(){
      printf("from module #3");
    }
};
```

Prints with python 2.7:

```
from module #1
from script #1
from module #2
from script #2
from module #3
from script #3
```

Prints with python 3.7:

```
from script #1
from script #2
from script #3
from module #1
from module #2
from module #3
```

If I replace printf() with std::cout(), I get the same behavior in **python 2.7**, but different behavior in **python 3.7**:

```
from module #1
from module #2
from module #3
from script #1
from script #2
from script #3
```

i.e. cpp module's prints are grouped together, appearing BEFORE any python script's print.

Comment: Have you considered flushing the output buffer after each call to printf/cout?

Comment: Got a sample so we can reproduce? Are you doing anything with GIL?

Comment: @brc-dd I tried calling fflush() after each printf() call. It behaves like std::cout (all prints coming from the cpp class were grouped together, and appeared at the beginning of run)

Comment: @user2881627 How about putting an `std::endl` with `std::cout`? Please add some code to your question so that we can verify what's happening.

Comment: @KennyOstrom - I added some code
@brc-dd: I tried using ```std::endl``` with ```std::cout``` and got a different result, but not the desired one (see results in the updated question)